# Dedupe CSS in Vue.js development mode

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli

I am working on a Vue.js project that heavily uses single file components. These components have scss styles associated with them.

In production mode the duplicate css that occurs from importing the same component multiple times is filtered out. But in development mode the same scss is imported multiple times.

This leads to slow downs with the chrome debugger when inspecting and modifying the css.

Does anone know a way to dedupe the css/scss attatched to single file components in developlment mode?

Here is my current vue config:

```
module.exports = {
  lintOnSave: false,
  configureWebpack: {
    resolve: {
      alias: require("./aliases.config").webpack
    },
    plugins: [
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: "jquery",
    _: "lodash"
  }),
  new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^\.\/locale$/, /moment$/)
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how we ended up solving it.

1. Import only pure SCSS in components (ie. mixins, variables, functions). If a file with CSS is imported in each component the sass loader will NOT dedupe the CSS in development mode.
2. In your vue config add the following to include you scss variables in every single file component:

   ```
      module.exports = {
        ... 
        css: {
           loaderOptions: {
             sass: {
               data: `
                 @import "@src/_variables.scss";
               `
             }
           }
         },
        ...
       }
   ```
3. Import your global scss in your app entry (main.js or equivalent)

   ```
   import "bootstrap";
   import "@src/global.scss";
   ```

In your global.scss file you can import your variables file so that it can also access your scss variables.